# php function add foreach array on another array to populate a select drop down

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I started this PHP function. This function is to populate a dropdown select menu in WordPress.

The acf/load_field hook helps me easily hook this in. See documentation here. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/filters/acfload_field/

This is my function which uses `get_posts` to query my `circuit` post_type. This bit works fine.

See below...

```
function my_circuit_field( $field )
{
    $circuits = get_posts(array(
        "post_type" => "circuit",
        "post_status" => "publish",
        "orderby" => "menu_order",
        "order" => "ASC",
        "posts_per_page"  => -1
    ));
    $field['choices'] = array();
    $field['choices'] = array(
        0 => 'Select a circuit...'
    );
    foreach($circuits as $circuit){
        $field['choices'] = array(
            $circuit->post_title => $circuit->post_title
        );
    }       
    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=event_calendar_circuit', 'my_circuit_field');
```

The problem I am having is that...

```
$field['choices'] = array(
    0 => 'Select a circuit...'
);
```

is not joining onto the front of this...

```
foreach($circuits as $circuit){
    $field['choices'] = array(
         $circuit->post_title => $circuit->post_title
    );
}
```

Only the `$circuits foreach` is showing in my dropdown, I would like 'Select a circuit' to appear as the first option in the dropdown select menu.

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use =, it replaces the current value with the one after the = sign. You're replacing the whole value of $field['choices'] each time you assign a new value.

You probably want to do something like

```
foreach($circuits as $circuit){
    $field['choices'][$circuit->post_title] = $circuit->post_title;
}
```

By the way, the line `$field['choices'] = array();` is useless in your code, as you change the value in the following line.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$field['choices'] = array(
    0 => 'Select a circuit...'
);
$arr = array();
foreach($circuits as $circuit){
    $arr = array(
       $circuit->post_title => $circuit->post_title
    );
    $field['choices'] = array_merge($field['choices'],$arr);
}
print_r($field);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [choices] => Array
        (
            [0] => Select a circuit...
            //and other fields 
            //with the 0 index value
            //same as you are requiring
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you also but I used the answer below which worked really well. Yours also works just as good. Thank you